# Including custom modules in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to reference a custom user module in a SS2.0 index script like so:

`/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 */
define([
'N/record', 'N/error', "SuiteScripts/MyFolder/src/My_Controller", 'N/crypto',`

Which works fine in sandbox. However when we deploy to production (bundle push) we get the following error when we call a RESTlet method:

> You do not have permission to load this module
>   SuiteScripts/MyFolder/src/My_Controller.js, it has an @NModuleScope of
>   SameAccount which restricts its availability to customization objects
>   created in account 1234566

All we did was:

1. create a RESTlet using our index file (SS2.0 does not allow you to define libraries)
2. deploy/bundle RESTlet
3. Upload the custom user modules (My_Controller.js) manually to the cabinet with Eclipse to the production account (CTRL+U)
4. Call a method on RESTlet (in production) using Postman

Can anyone see what we are doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Looks like I may be missing the "@NModuleSc​o​p​e Public" annotation?

Comment: Is that work?Otherwise,I think you should use relative paths,if you bundle push the custom module file.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, you are missing  "@NModuleSc​o​p​e Public". See https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49326

You can set the argument to any of Public, TargetAccount or SameAccount. This allows you some control over what other scripts can load your module. If you do public, any bundle can run the script. If you want to avoid this, you can leave it to SameAccount and make sure your My_controller.js is in the same bundle as the restlet.

Comment: This has been done (@NModuleSc​o​p​e Public) but NetSuite is still ignoring my NModuleScope. Really frustrating, It keeps saying it's set to SameAccount

Comment: @Coldstar SameAccount is the default setting, so for some reason you're not picking up the NModuleScope. The JSDOC comment has to be notated in a very specific way per https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43522, so make sure that it's formatted correctly. If you figure it out, feel free to submit your own answer to your question, since you're in a better position to test it out than myself.